# Undefined variable in list comprehension when defining class variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, list-comprehension

When defining a class and assigning it a few class variables, I came across the need to use a class variable I'd already defined to generate another variable, within a list comprehension.
Stripped down to the core, my problem is as follows

```
class Foo():
    d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    e = [2 * x for x in range(100)]

    # Works as expected
    # prints [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ...]
    print(e)

    baz = [
        e[i] # NameError: 'e' is not defined
        for i in d
    ]

x = Foo()
```

However, once I get into the comprehension, I get a NameError, telling me that `'e' is not defined`. I know for a fact then when not in a class definition, this works

```
d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
e = [2 * x for x in range(100)]

baz = [
    e[i]
    for i in d
]

print(baz) # Works as expected, producing [2, 4, 6, 8, 10...]
```

So evidently, being in a class-definition scope seems to be messing things up. I've tried prepending `e[i]` with `self.` and `cls.` (admittedly out of desperation) but to no avail.
What am I missing?

Several Google searches haven't yielded anything, but if this is a duplicate and anybody can point me in the right direction I'd be glad.

Comment: Weird; this fails in Python 3.5.4, but works as desired in 2.7 ...